# Can I get rid of the search engine suggestion on the Firefox omnibar?

Tags: firefox

I'd like to get rid of the suggestion when I type into the Firefox omnibar. I got rid of the suggestions for my non-default browsers, but it still shows up with a blue bar that just repeats what I'm typing into the omnibar, plus a message that says "search with google."

Can I get rid of that box altogether? I wonder if it's possible to edit the userChrome file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent *any* suggestions:

- In the URL Bar, type `About:config`
- Accept any liability ;-)
- In the `Search` box at the top of the page, enter `maxri`
- Double-click on `browser.urlbar.maxRichResults` and set to `0` (zero).

Conversely, for those who want to see more suggestions in the drop-down, increase the number.

It would be nice if [this setting](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.urlbar.maxRichResults) were made more obvious; perhaps in the `Options | Search` items.

Comment: That is so good. Is it possible to get rid of the grey bar that appears in its place?

Comment: If you mean the bar with a list of *al* search engines, that's *always* shown at the bottom of the Search suggestions. Perhaps deleting all search engines might prevent it from showing, or another config setting might.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're already familiar with this but in case anyone new sees this, you can customize almost any part of the UI in Firefox with [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css) in the [chrome](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Chrome) folder.

You mentioned in a comment you want to get rid of the suggestions bar completely. This will hide the bar so nothing will appear when using the omnibar.

```
#urlbar-results
{
  display: none !important;
}
```